# Copy all values in a column to a new column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is a very basic question, I just can not seem to find an answer.

I have a dataframe like this, called `df`:

```
  A     B     C
 a.1   b.1   c.1
 a.2   b.2   c.2
 a.3   b.3   c.3
```

Then I extract all the rows from `df`, where column `B` has a value of 'b.2'.  I assign these results to `df_2`.

```
df_2 = df[df['B'] == 'b.2']
```

`df_2` becomes:

```
  A     B     C
 a.2   b.2   c.2
```

Then, I copy all the values in column `B` to a new column named `D`. Causing `df_2` to become:

```
  A     B     C     D
 a.2   b.2   c.2   b.2
```

When I preform an assignment like this:

```
df_2['D'] = df_2['B']
```

I get the following warning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
> using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the the caveats in the documentation:
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

---

I have also tried using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) when creating `df_2` like this:

```
df_2 = df.loc[df['B'] == 'b.2']
```

However, I still get the warning.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `a.1` means? Is it a string?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can simply assign the `B` to the new column , Like -

```
df['D'] = df['B']
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([['a.1','b.1','c.1'],['a.2','b.2','c.2'],['a.3','b.3','c.3']],columns=['A','B','C'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
     A    B    C
0  a.1  b.1  c.1
1  a.2  b.2  c.2
2  a.3  b.3  c.3

In [4]: df['D'] = df['B']                  #<---What you want.

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
     A    B    C    D
0  a.1  b.1  c.1  b.1
1  a.2  b.2  c.2  b.2
2  a.3  b.3  c.3  b.3

In [6]: df.loc[0,'D'] = 'd.1'

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
     A    B    C    D
0  a.1  b.1  c.1  d.1
1  a.2  b.2  c.2  b.2
2  a.3  b.3  c.3  b.3
```

Comment: You used `df['D'] = df['B'] right? You should not get that , did you do something else?

Comment: Thank you! I get:

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
 df['D'] = df['B']

Would it be better to iterate over each row pulling out the value and assigning it to the new column? Or is this a non-issue?

Comment: Like i said , did you use `df['D'] = df['B']` ? If not what else did you use?

Comment: @AnandSKumar we get the warning when applying your solution: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.`

Comment: I tried using `df = df.copy()` and then `df['D'] = df['B']` I did not get any warning

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga I don't see any warnings on Pandas `0.24.2` and Python `3.7`. Could you share your environment where you see the warnings?

Comment: Unexpected error: (<class 'KeyError'>, KeyError('Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported

Comment: I first copied the values to a new dataframe using `df.copy()` and then used assignment `df["A"] = df["B"]`, and it worked without getting any warnings.

Comment: @JustinBuchanan this happens if you copy the values to a new column in a view (shallow copy) of the original dataframe. For example: `df2 = df1[["A", "B"]]` and then `df2["C"] = df2["B"]` Instead, try `df2 = df1[["A", "B"]].copy()` before`df2["C"] = df2["B"]`. This makes sure that `df2` is a deep copy and not just a shallow copy (view) of `df1 `.

Answer (score 36):

The problem is in the line before the one that throws the warning. When you create df_2 that's where you're creating a copy of a slice of a dataframe. Instead, when you create df_2, use .copy() and you won't get that warning later on.

```
df_2 = df[df['B'] == 'b.2'].copy()
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you

Comment: what exactly does .copy() do different here?

Comment: The difference with .copy() is that it returns a new object instead of a view of the original object. So if you change the new object, the original one won't be altered.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the method [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas.DataFrame.assign). It returns a new DataFrame so you can use it in chains with other methods.

```
df.assign(D=df.B)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D
0  a.1  b.1  c.1  b.1
1  a.2  b.2  c.2  b.2
2  a.3  b.3  c.3  b.3
```

Comment: This is the only one of these answers that does not trigger a `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning as of 2022.

Answer (score 5):

I think the correct access method is using the index:

```
df_2.loc[:,'D'] = df_2['B']
```

Comment: It will raise "SettingWithCopyWarning"

Comment: @HarperKoo What version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

df['D'] = df['B'].values

Comment: I still see the copy warning when using this one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a.1', 'a.2', 'a.3'],
    'B': ['b.1', 'b.2', 'b.3'],
    'C': ['c.1', 'c.2', 'c.3']})
```

Your answer is in the paragraph "[Setting with enlargement](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement)" in the section on "Indexing and selecting data" in the documentation on Pandas.

It says:

> A DataFrame can be enlarged on either axis via .loc.

So what you need to do is simply one of these two:

```
df.loc[:, 'D'] = df.loc[:, 'B']
df.loc[:, 'D'] = df['B']
```

Answer (score 2):

The question was asked a while ago, but my response could help others.

I had a similar situation. When you sliced a dataframe into `df_2`, you need to reset index,

```
df_2 = df_2.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Now you can run the command without warning

```
df_2['D'] = df_2['B']
```

Answer (score 1):

[`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) lets you assign `B` to the new columns `D` right away:

```
In [8]: df.eval('D=B', inplace=True)

In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
     A    B    C    D
0  a.1  b.1  c.1  b.1
1  a.2  b.2  c.2  b.2
2  a.3  b.3  c.3  b.3
```

Since `inplace=True` you don't need to assign it back to `df`.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on these solutions, here is some helpful code illustrating :

```
#
# Copying columns in pandas without slice warning
#
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

#
# copies column B into new column D
df.loc[:,'D'] = df['B']
print df

#
# creates new column 'E' with values -99
# 
# But copy command replaces those where 'B'>0 while others become NaN (not copied)
df['E'] = -99
print df
df['E'] = df[df['B']>0]['B'].copy()
print df

#
# creates new column 'F' with values -99
# 
# Copy command only overwrites values which meet criteria 'B'>0
df['F']=-99
df.loc[df['B']>0,'F'] = df[df['B']>0]['B'].copy()
print df
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do create a new column in a pandas DataFrame based on the values of an existing column, is to use the assign() method:

```
df.assign(D=df.B)
```

This way you can create a new column and assign it a value, while keeping the original DataFrame unchanged.

The `df['D'] = df['B']` solution may cause problems and should be avoided.