# Why isnt df["ColumA"] = df_2["ColumnB"] working as expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

given two `DataFrames`:

```
#df1
value         Symbol       Date   Type        Value
1109914    AUD 2016-01-29  value   64587.9121    
1109949    CAD 2016-01-29  value   65357.1429
1109970    CHF 2016-01-29  value  111881.8681
1110012     DX 2016-01-29  value   91256.4103

#df2
volas         Symbol       Date  Type     Value
1109915    AUD 2016-01-29  vola  518.5091
1109950    CAD 2016-01-29  vola  360.9474
1109971    CHF 2016-01-29  vola  767.1880
1110013     DX 2016-01-29  vola  495.8913
1110041    EUR 2016-01-29  vola  876.6861
1110062    GBP 2016-01-29  vola  462.6425
```

If I want to add a columnd to df1 from df2, naturally, I'd try this:

```
df1["volas"] = df2["Value"]
```

However, this returns a Series with `nan` values (and hence fills the new column with such):

```
1109921   NaN
1110089   NaN
1110138   NaN
1110159   NaN
1110257   NaN
1110450   NaN
1110618   NaN
1110667   NaN
1110688   NaN
```

However, if I do this:

```
market_values['Volas'] = [i for i in market_volas.Value]
```

The values are assigned as expected.

**Why?**
I simply cannot see where the problem is, especially because my initial attempt is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675861/copy-all-values-in-a-column-to-a-new-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: The indices don't align so you get `NaN` the second attempt adds the scalar value which has no associated index value which is why it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is problem that `index` in `df1` is different as `index` in `df2`.

If length od `indexes` is equal, you can use [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
df1["volas"] = df2["Value"].values
print (df1)
     value Symbol        Date   Type        Value     volas
0  1109914    AUD  2016-01-29  value   64587.9121  518.5091
1  1109949    CAD  2016-01-29  value   65357.1429  360.9474
2  1109970    CHF  2016-01-29  value  111881.8681  767.1880
3  1110012     DX  2016-01-29  value   91256.4103  495.8913
```

Answer (score 3):

Think of

```
df1["volas"] = df2["Value"]
```

as doing a `merge` on the index of the two dataframes. What you're probably after is an actual merge based on some matching columns, e.g.

```
df1.merge(df2, on=["Symbol","Date"])
```

which will add the columns from `df2` based on matches with the other columns, or, if they are of the same length

```
df1["volas"] = df2.Value.values
```

which is basically your loop solution.